# Bigcommerce checkbox addons to product

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to have a checkbox on the product page that are upselling the current product? For example if the user wants to buy a computer they might want to add a mouse, is that possible to implement on the product page for the computer by adding a checkbox that says "Add a mouse +50 SEK", and mouse in this case is referring to another existing product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

natively you can add a customized checkbox value to your pdp. You would do this under Products > View > Edit > Customizations. Select checkbox. Then enter rules to increase the price when selected. However, this is not tied directly to the product, so you'd have to run your own custom logic to handle inventory if you go this route.
[image]

Another option is to use a picklist. This is in the same location as checkbox. However the difference is that you can directly link this to a product on your storefront and not have to worry about inventory as it can be handled within BC if you select that option.
[image]

A third option is to use an app from the App Marketplace. I've used the BuyButtons app + an HTML widget on the pdp in a quick test to see how this would look. It would need some tweaking to get it to how you'd like, but it was fairly straight forward. [image]

There are likely many other ways to accomplish this, though! These are just some native options & an app option. Thanks!